# Strapi Admin Panel keeps loading

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi

I have successfully setup strapi api on an EC2-instance. I have also made required nginx reverse proxy config.

```
`server_name  _;

<Other locations>

location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/admin;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}`
```

when i access the instance_ip/admin it displays the strapi admin login page, but after i enter the credentials, the page keeps on loading. I find no error logs in strapi terminal. Everything works perfect in local though

Reverse proxy nginx, running strapi along with the other servers on dedicated ports
Expected:
Strapi admin panel to create collections.